# The Gwt Designer CSS viewer can not find the css file when using CLientBundle

Tags: css, gwt-designer, clientbundle

I would like to use the CSS viewer (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/css_support) integrated in GWT designer in order to manage my css styles....

But I can not add my css stylesheet created in 'src/client/resources/'. The css viewer just find the css inside the WAR directory. Thanks for the help (how to indicate to gwt designer to find/add another css file not located in the WAR directory).

Comment: I have the same issue, is there anyone that can help with this?